# how to test websocket in Spring framework?

Tags: spring, sockets, testing, websocket

I have a spring framework project with websocket and I want to test the websocket. but I don't know exactly how to make the test. show one simple test for an websocket please. thank you.

Comment: Which type of test you are talking about , functional test pr unit test or integration test ?

Comment: I want unit tests.